# Missing stdout and GUI after running cross-compiled wxWidget app on Windows 10

Tags: c++11, cmake, cross-compiling, wxwidgets, mingw-w64

I downloaded the wxWidgets-3.1.3 source code and built it with the mingw-w64 on Ubuntu 18.04 by running these commands:

```bash
./configure --prefix=build/win64 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-cxx=11 --with-msw --enable-stl --enable-debug
make -j4
make install
```

My cpp code contains:

```cpp
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  std::cout<<"Debug start main()"<<std::endl;
  fprintf(stderr,"...");
  sleep(3);
}
```

Then I build my application without including any wxWidget code (and only linking to the wxWidgets libs) for testing with CMake:

```
find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED COMPONENTS gl core base aui)
add_executable(myapp main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myapp ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})
```

I can build it by calling below command from the build folder:

```
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../cmake/mingw-w64.toolchain
      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin
      -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
..
```

The CMake toolchain file contains:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME WindowsStore)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 10.0)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR x86_64)

set(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX x86_64-w64-mingw32)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-gcc-posix)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-g++-posix)
set(CMAKE_RC_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-windres)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -fstack-protector-strong")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_INIT "")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "-O0 -g -pg -Wextra")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O2 -Wall -Wextra")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fstack-protector-strong -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT "")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-O0 -g -pg")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O2 -Wall")

# where is the target environment located
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
    /usr/${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX} # mingw folder
    ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} 
)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)

# search headers and libraries in the target environment
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

I copy the exe file and run on Windows 10. However, I can't see the console output. The application does the sleep. Running the exe file with the gdb from the installed MinGW for Windows also doesn't print the printf output. If I remove the wxWidgets library from the `target_link_libraries()`, I can see the console output.

If the main.cpp contains the Hello World tutorial code from this site https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_helloworld.html, I can see the GUI.

What I observed, starting with `wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);` without `int main()` in the main.cpp can show the GUI correctly. However, starting the GUI with these code doesn't work:

```cpp
#include <wx/wx.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  wxEntryStart(wxArgc, argv);
  if (!wxTheApp || !wxTheApp->CallOnInit()){
    std::cout << "Failed!\n" << std::flush;
    return false;
  }
}
```

Any hint why?

Comment: are you trying to build the console or GUI application? If the former - get rid of the core library. If the latter - std::cout is not supported. To answer the second question - why do you want to use wxWidgets not by official way?

Comment: My goal is to build a GUI application. However, since the GUI can't start and I can't debug my appication, I started from 0 with the printf() or std::cout. Yes, you are right, getting rid of the core lib solve the printf issue, but I need the core lib for my GUI app. Oh, I thought using the configure is the official way. What would be the official way?

Comment: don't use main. Look at the minimal sample and see how to write a GUI application with wxWidgets. Then check all other different samples to understand how to operate the library. Good luck.

Comment: I need the main() because several backend threads should be started based on several arguments and flags.

Comment: no you don't. You can do parsing of the command line arguments in the `wxApp::OnInit()` override and then start you threads as required,.

Comment: I don't understand what you meant with overriding `wxApp::OnInit()`.  I call `wxApp::OnInit()` in my function `bool MyApp::OnInit(){}` which also creates the `class MainWindow: public wxFrame`. Did you mean that I should start my threads inside `MyApp::OnInit()`? How can I share objects between the wxFrame and wxPanel objects wihtout declaring a global object?  Thanks @Igor!

Comment: Also, base your application on the minimal sample. Parse the command line arguments inside the wxApp::OnInit(), then create your threads and then start the GUI. Its simple as that. And yes - the threasds should start inside the wxApp::OnInit() IF your application demands that. There is no need for the main() function. Your app is GUI-based.

Comment: First of all, if you really have long experience with C++ then you should be precise rather than telling me don't have experience. wxWidgets is not C++, and if I hadn't have to support a legacy code with wxWidgets, I would have used another GUI library. MyApp has member pointers of several wxPanel objects (composition). Normally, I parse the argv, but how can I parse the argv inside the OnInit()?. I found out this example https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Command-Line_Arguments, is this really what you meant? Thanks for the fast reply!

Comment: for the argument parsing, check the console or docview sample. The latter shows what to do with the parsed stuff and how it operates - depending on the parameter it runs in SDI, MDI or AUI mode. In you case you will just run different threads as needed.